# FLASK python web:MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Tags: python, mysql

I tried to make a simple login and registration system using the python flask framework using the Mysql database, but I have the following problem when, can anyone provide help with my problem?
[Screen shoot message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Gje.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mysql instance is up and running

```
service mysqld start
```

if this doesn't solve the problem, check the my.cnf file for the location of the mysql.sock file

```
[mysqld]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

[client]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

you may have to link that file to /etc/mysql.sock